# Changing listing numbers

Tags: listings, counters, line-numbering

I want to change the numbers of a listing based on certain rules:

- Line 10: no number
- Line 11 onwards: the number that corresponds to the line+5

The displayed numbers should thus be: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, , 16, 17, 18, etc.

The contents of the listing are obtained from a separate file.

So far, I am trying this out with `if` statements, but it is not working:

```
\renewcommand\thelstnumber{%
\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=10  \else \ifnum\value{lstnumber}>10 \arabic{lstnumber + 5} \else\arabic{lstnumber}\fi\fi
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you cannot perform arithmetic calculations within `\arabic` natively. For ease-of-use, use [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) to perform (expandable) `int`eger calculations/`eval`uations using `\inteval`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xfp}

\renewcommand\thelstnumber{%
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}=10
  \else
    \ifnum\value{lstnumber}>10
      \inteval{\value{lstnumber} + 5}%
    \else
      \arabic{lstnumber}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers = left]
Line A
Line B
Line C
Line D
Line E
Line F
Line G
Line H
Line I
Line J
Line K
Line L
Line M
Line N
Line O
Line P
Line Q
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

If you can't use `xfp` for whatever reason, you can use

```
\renewcommand\thelstnumber{%
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}=10
  \else
    \ifnum\value{lstnumber}>10
      \the\numexpr\value{lstnumber} + 5\relax%
    \else
      \arabic{lstnumber}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I am using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) for my project, and `xfp` is not natively supported.
How should I install it?

Comment: When copying+pasting your snippet in [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com), I get the following compiler error:
`! LaTeX Error: File \`xfp.sty' not found.
l.4 ^^M`

Comment: I contacted Overleaf's customer support, and they replied the following:

The `xfp` package is available on Overleaf V2, but the version of `xfp` we have does not provide the `\inteval` command yet, so that code snippet in the `tex.sx` answer would also fail.

However the `xfp` package isn't necessary for what you're trying to achieve, as we can use `\the\numexpr` instead of `\inteval`

Comment: Werner, I think your answer solves the issue, but maybe you could update it with the last feedback from Overleaf for the sake of completeness, and then it can be accepted?

Comment: @tli: Yes. As mentioned, I use [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) due to the convenience and ease-of-use. I've updated my answer to highlight the alternative.